# Using noise suppression module in webrtc in android

Tags: java, android, c, webrtc, noise

I am developing a Speaker Identification app in android and I wanted to process the audio input from microphone before analysing it with the speaker identification algorithm. I came across to the **noise suppression module in WebRTC**. I have already set it up in android using JNI.

I have a question about the function **WebRtcNs_Process** in the module. In the header file, it says **int WebRtcNs_Process**(NsHandle* NS_inst, short* spframe, short* spframe_H, short* outframe, short* outframe_H);

According to the header file, 
**spframe**       : Pointer to speech frame buffer for **L band** 
**spframe_H**     : Pointer to speech frame buffer for **H band** 
**outframe**      : Pointer to output frame for **L band** 
**outframe_H**    : Pointer to output frame for **H band**

Does anyone know what these arguments refer to? aka What are **L band** and **H band**? What is the difference between speech frame buffer for L band and that for H band?

THANKS!!

Comment: You can go to [wideband-voice-voip](http://what-when-how.com/voip/wideband-voice-voip/) for some info.

Comment: @BillHoo What did you do to split L-band & H-band audio. Do you use WebRTC's function (WebRtcSpl_AnalysisQMF) or use your function. If use WebRTC, what parameters I need pass into for filter_state1 and filter_state2. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

For those who comes across this problem, if you take a look at the audio_processing module in WebRTC, you will find it only does band splitting for [super-wb](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/stable/webrtc/+/master/modules/audio_processing/splitting_filter.h), i.e. 32kHz sampling rate.

So if you are using 8kHz or 16kHz sampling rate, you can set spframe_H and outframe_H to NULL, and set spframe and outframe to your raw audio data. If you are using 32kHz, then you need to do band splitting as [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/stable/webrtc/+/master/modules/audio_processing/audio_processing_impl.cc)